# how to refresh the page when i click the asp image button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio

When i click the image button, page should refresh and show the data i tried in javascipt ,jquery but i am  not getting please someone help for this..

Thanks in Advance.

here is my code : 
roport.ascx

```
<td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-right: 0px;">

                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnViewReport" ImageUrl="../../../_layouts/15/1033/IMAGES/eContracts/view-report-btn.png" runat="server" Text="View Report" 
                                 OnClientClick="ShowFilters(); return true;"/>

                            </td>
```

I used jquery like this, but this is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnViewReport').click(function () { location.reload(true); 
        location.reload();
    })
})
```

when i click the image button data are viewing but page not refreshing.
Clientside when i click the image button page should refresh.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing semi-colons. Also, why are are you calling location.reload twice?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnViewReport').click(function () { 
        location.reload(true); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried like this but is not working.when i click the button the page is not reloading.

Comment: Have you tried F12 to see if there's an error?